# Compile time error : The "GenerateResource" task's outputs could not be retrieved

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

In visual studio Some project are working fine but some projects through error shown in screenshot
I searched a lot but cant find proper solution

[image]

Comment: did you find a solution for this problem ?